# Opening AD from vb.net with different credentials

Tags: vb.net, process, active-directory, passwords

I have found the following code

```
    Dim p As New ProcessStartInfo With {
        .FileName = "c:\Windows\System32\dsa.msc",
        .Arguments = "/SAVECRED /user:DOMAIN\username"
    }


    ' Start the process
    Process.Start(p)
```

I want to be able to pass the following cmd that prompts for username

```
c:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /SAVECRED /user:DOMAIN\username "c:\Windows\System32\mmc.exe c:\Windows\System32\dsa.msc"
```

Which works by opening the app but does not pass the username or prompt for password, I cant figure out how to forse the different cred along with arguments.

Ideas ??

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out - here is the code i used

```
Function ConvertToSecureString(ByVal str As String)
    Dim password As New SecureString
    For Each c As Char In str.ToCharArray
        password.AppendChar(c)
    Next
    Return password
End Function

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim passwordString As String
    passwordString = "..........."
    Dim password As SecureString = ConvertToSecureString(passwordString)


    ' New ProcessStartInfo created
    Dim p As New ProcessStartInfo

    ' Specify the location of the binary
    p.FileName = "mmc.exe"
    p.WorkingDirectory = "c:\Windows\System32\"
    ' Use these arguments for the process
    p.Arguments = "dsa.msc"
    p.Domain = "........"
    p.UserName = "......."
    p.Password = password
    p.UseShellExecute = False
    ' Start the process
    Process.Start(p)


End Sub
```